# Cakephp FormHelper not outputting "<form>" tags

Tags: php, cakephp, forms, helper, form-helpers

So I have a users controller with an action called "*selfView*" it looks like this:
(*users_controller.php*)

```
function selfView() {
  $user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));
  $formms = $this->Form->find('all', array('fields' => array('Form.id', 'Form.name'), 'recursive' => -1));
  $this->set(compact('user', 'formms'));
  $this->render('view');
}
```

This renders a profile page which has one form on it. This is the **first** form rendered on the page and it works just fine as you would expect.

View code snippet:
(*users/view.ctp*)

```
<div id="passwordChange">
        <?php echo $form->create('User', array( 'action' =>'updatePass' ));?>
          <fieldset>
            <legend><?php __('Change Password');?></legend>
            <?php
              $options = array('type'=>'password', 'div' => array('class' => 'required'));
              echo $form->input(__('old_password', true), $options);

              $options = array('div' => array('class' => 'required'), 'error' => array('confirmPassword' => __('Passwords do not match please try again',true), 'noempty' => __('Please provide a password',true)));
              echo $form->input(__('password', true), $options);

              $options = array('type'=>'password', 'div' => array('class' => 'required'));
              echo $form->input(__('confirmation_password', true), $options);

              echo $form->hidden('User.id', array('value' => $user['User']['id']));
            ?>
          </fieldset>
        <?php echo $ajax->submit(__('Change Password', true), array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'updatePass'),
                   'update' => 'storage', 
                   'complete' => '$("#UserUpdatePassForm input[type=password]").val(""); '));
    $form->end();?>  
                    <a href="#">Cancel</a> 
      </div>
```

the **HTML** that is Produced form "*users/view.ctp*":

```
<form action="/high-school-app/users/updatePass" method="post" id="UserUpdatePassForm">
  <fieldset style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Change Password</legend>
    <div class="required">
      <label for="UserOldPassword">Old Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="UserOldPassword" value="" name="data[User][old_password]">
    </div>
    <div class="required required">
      <label for="UserPassword">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="UserPassword" value="" name="data[User][password]">
    </div><div class="required required">
      <label for="UserConfirmationPassword">Confirmation Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="UserConfirmationPassword" value="" name="data[User][confirmation_password]">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="UserId" value="" name="data[User][id]">
  </fieldset>
  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return false;" id="submit2026598409" value="Change Password" update="storage">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //&lt;![CDATA[
  jQuery('#submit2026598409').click( function() { jQuery('#submit2026598409').parents('form').ajaxSubmit({beforeSend:function(request) {request.setRequestHeader('X-Update', 'storage');}, complete:function(request, textStatus) {$("#UserUpdatePassForm input[type=password]").val(""); }, success:function(data, textStatus) {jQuery('#storage').html(data);}, async:true, type:'post', url:'/high-school-app/users/updatePass'}); return false;});
  //]]&gt;
  </script> 
  <a href="#">Cancel</a> 
</form>
```

Then I call and element that will also render a form.
(*users/view.ctp*)

```
echo $this->element('my_apps' , array('applications' => $applications));
```

And then this is where it all goes wrong.  No matter what I try I can not get this second form to print out correctly. The middle part of the form will print out,just not the opening and closing tags. With out them the form is useless to me. At this point and I really do not want to write it out by hand.

This is the code in my element that I am trying to use to output the form(*elements/my_apps.ctp*):

```
<?php echo $form->create('Applications', array( 'url' => array('controller' => 'applications', 'action' => 'assign',  'id' => null))); ?>
      <fieldset>
        <legend><?php __('Assign Application to User');?></legend>
        <?php
          $options = array('--' => __('Select One',true), 'test' => 'test', 'test2' => 'test2');
          echo $form->label('Application.form_id', __('Form Name',true).":");
          echo $form->select('Application.form_id', $options, $selected = '--');

          echo $form->hidden('Application.user_id', array('value' => $user['User']['id']));
        ?>
      </fieldset>
<?php echo $form->end(__('Assign', true));?>
```

this is what "*elements/my_apps.ctp*" prints out:

```
<fieldset style="display: none;">
  <input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Assign Application to User</legend>
  <label for="ApplicationFormId">Form Name:</label>
  <select id="ApplicationFormId" name="data[Application][form_id]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option selected="selected" value="--">Select One</option>
    <option value="test">test</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="ApplicationUserId" value="" name="data[Application][user_id]">
</fieldset>
<div class="submit">
  <input type="submit" value="Assign">
</div>
```

It **WILL NOT** Print the opening and closing tags which should be something like this:

```
<form action="/high-school-app/applications/assign" method="post" id="ApplicationAssignForm">
 .....
 .....
</form>
```

Any ideas? Something that I should try to do to debug would be helpful.

Update:

I just tried witting the code in by hand and even that is being stripped out. Is there some sort of post-processing going? Could that be responsible for removing my form tags?

Comment: there shouldn't be any post processing, depending on what you mean by "writing by hand".  Did you just have the HTML inside the CTP file?  Because that for sure shouldn't be stripped out.  Would you put a link on pastebin with your layout file and your template file for me?  I've had this prob before, but can't recall how I solved it.  Seeing your layout/view files might help.

Comment: Sorry, posting from Germany. I tried writing the html in the ctp file and it still stripped out the "form" tags. 

here is a pastebin link:
http://pastebin.com/m5e68275d

if there is anything else that might help let me know. 

Again sorry for the delay.

Comment: so no answers I juet did an ajax request for the form and diplay it in a modal window. works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong yet, but can I suggest that for your sanity, you either use a different name for the variable `$options` in the first form, or better still, write the array inline. It is more common to see `$options` used to pass the selection choices as you have done in the second form. I.e. save $options for 'options'.

In your function `selfView()` you don't appear to assign values to `applications` & `formms`.

My personal preference is to write this:

```
<?php echo $form->submit(__('Assign', true));
      echo $form->end();?>
```

like this:

```
<?php echo $form->end(__('Assign', true)) ?>
```

I think it makes the code slightly more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on making my code more readable I have made some changes to incorporate you suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

In your first form your are not echoing $form->end() so the form is not properly closing.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. If you don't echo the closing $form->end() the second form won't render at all.